# How to redirect 404 requests to homepage in Django single page app using Nginx?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a django single page application. Currently when you visit a url on the site that doesn't exist a 404 error is displayed. However, in this case I want to redirect to the homepage of the site. I am not sure if I should how to do this with Nginx, or is there a way to do this within Django? Attached is my Nginx file below. I tried using the below setting but it did not work.

```
error_page 404 = @foobar;

location @foobar {
  return 301 /webapps/mysite/app/templates/index.html;
}


upstream mysite_wsgi_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/webapps/mysite/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name kanjisama.com;
    rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen              443;
    server_name         kanjisama.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/kanjisama.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/kanjisama.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/mysite/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /webapps/mysite/logs/nginx_error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/mysite/app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/mysite/media/;
    }

    location / {
        if (-f /webapps/mysite/maintenance_on.html) {
            return 503;
        }

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://mysite_wsgi_server;
            break;
        }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/mysite/app/mysite/templates/;
    }

    error_page 503 /maintenance_on.html;
    location = /maintenance_on.html {
        root /webapps/mysite/;
    }

    error_page 404 = @foobar;

    location @foobar {
      return 301 /webapps/mysite/app/templates/index.html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

First, create a view to handle all 404 requests.

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import redirect

def view_404(request, exception=None):
    # make a redirect to homepage
    # you can use the name of url or just the plain link
    return redirect('/') # or redirect('name-of-index-url')
```

Second, put the following in your project's `urls.py`:

```
handler404 = 'myapp.views.view_404' 
# replace `myapp` with your app's name where the above view is located
```

Comment: From [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#handler404), if you implement a custom view, be sure it accepts request and exception arguments and returns an HttpResponseNotFound.

Answer (score -1):

### 404 page Error handling

->set DEBUG=False in settings.py

-> handler404='appname.views.view_404' add this line at the bottom of the root urls.py file.

->add this function to the views file of the app which is mentioned in handler404

```
def view_404(request,exception=None)
    return redirect('redirect-url-name')
```

Comment: This solution has already been provided in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42469671/5320906).  When answering old questions, please ensure that your answer provides a distinct and valuable contribution to the Q&A.

Comment: i told you to add this line in root settings.py file set DEBUG=False in settings.py