# angular django rewrite unmatched urls to index.html (angular app)

Tags: django, angular, http-status-code-404, reroute

I have a django server and an angular app.

I am able to launch the angular app and navigate to the various parts of the site using links i have added to the app.

But if I want to go to a part of the site directly I get a 404 error.

example if I have a link in my app that directs me to

```
niftysite.com/team
```

it works

but if I put in my browsers url

```
niftysite.com/team
```

it fails with 404

I understand this is because the default behavior is to look for the link to the page in the servers urls.

I also understand that the fix is to have server side 404s redirect to the angular index.html page with the route params included.

My question is how?

I have already started on an implementation but I am not sure how to fix it. Any guidance the rest of the way through would be helpful.

here is what I have so far.

urls.py

```
handler404 = views.error_404
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def error_404(request):
    data = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', data)
```

similar to this question, but I am not using Nginx

[How to redirect 404 requests to homepage in Django single page app using Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469306/how-to-redirect-404-requests-to-homepage-in-django-single-page-app-using-nginx)

Comment: If I understood you question correctly; urlpatterns = ['^.*$', views.error_404, name='error_404']

Comment: @MihirKavatkar thank you I will give it a try. Now what of the route? Does it persist? Is that normal in django? Example will I redirect to the index page with the url info still in state?

Comment: I need to look into the part where if the url info lives in the state or not but my general way of handling, is adding a     ui-view(UI router) in the index.html of the app and place a $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/niftysite.com/team') while defining my states.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation:

urls.py

```
url(r'^.*$', views.PassToAngular.as_view())
```

make sure this url is the last url in your urls array.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


    class PassToAngular(TemplateView):

        def get(self, request, **kwargs):
            return render(request, 'index.html', context= None)
```

thanks to MihirKavatkar for your help!