# Django redirect a custom rendered 404.html template

Tags: django

I want to redirect a custom template when an invalid url is entered in my Django website.
When an incorrect URL, for example /home/ll, is entered then 404.html is shown on the screen and the url is redirected to /error.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views here it describes how to customize your 404 errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect 404 requests to homepage in Django single page app using Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469306/how-to-redirect-404-requests-to-homepage-in-django-single-page-app-using-nginx)

Comment: This is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469306/how-to-redirect-404-requests-to-homepage-in-django-single-page-app-using-nginx.

Comment: is there a way to redirect and show a custom error message on the screen from a template 404.html?

Comment: Also I'd like to redirect to /error which isn't recognized by Django.